# Python Pygame Newbie Code Showing Blank Screen

Tags: python, pygame

I execute the following code and just get a blank (black) window.

The window caption shows but I have not yet gotten the images to load (I tried using other images than the ones utilized too).  The .py file and the images are in the same directory.

```
background_image_filename='checkmark.jpg'
mouse_image_filename='digestive_bw.png'
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*
from sys import exit


pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,800),0,32)
#pygame.display.set_caption("Hello, Howdy, Mate, and Hi there world!")


background=pygame.image.load(background_image_filename).convert()
mouse_cursor=pygame.image.load(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

screen.blit(background,(0,0))

x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
x-=mouse_cursor.get_width() /2
y=-mouse_cursor.get_height() /2
screen.blit(mouse_cursor,(x,y))

pygame.display.update()
```

I have installed python 3.2 with pygame 1.9.2. If I can't get this to work I will consider uninstalling those and installing 3.1 + 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the code inside the loop, and use a clock to avoid using all the cpu:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x-=mouse_cursor.get_width() /2
    y=-mouse_cursor.get_height() /2
    screen.blit(mouse_cursor,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)  # keep 30 fps
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else you might want to do, you put y=- at one point and x-= right next to it.  I dont' think you meant to do that.

Answer (score 0):

tip: You can simplify `width / 2` when using `Rect`. They have other useful dynamic properties too: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html ( width, center, centerx, topleft, etc... )

Code:

```
mouse_cursor=pygame.image.load(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()
mouse_rect = mouse_cursor.get_rect()

mouse_rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
screen.blit(mouse_cursor, mouse_rect)
pygame.display.update()
```

Which was:

```
mouse_cursor=pygame.image.load(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()

x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
x-=mouse_cursor.get_width() /2
y=-mouse_cursor.get_height() /2
screen.blit(mouse_cursor,(x,y))
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```
pygame.display.flip(screen)?
```

also need to update

```
pygame.display.update(screen)
```